# Netty SSL Handler Unit Tests

Tags: testing, ssl, handler, netty

I'm about to embark on configuring the ssl handler for our server. I have looked at the secure chat example a few times. I'm just trying to formulate how I can write a unit test using the embedder testing classes.

Does anyone have a netty unit testing example for the ssl handler setup? I was wondering if anyone would like to share their efforts in this area. I'm still not sure how to begin.

Many thanks.

Comment: I will post something if get some solution. I am looking for solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do unit tests for Netty handler pipelines that included StartTLS and compression. I found it easier just to use a loopback socket rather than try to wire up the encoder/decoder embedders.

I did use the embedders for the more isolated tests dealing specifically with individual encoding and decoding handlers but when testing the full pipeline I think a loopback socket is the way to go.